# ASP.Net identity provider in Xamarin forms

Tags: asp.net, xamarin.forms, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to authenticate my app users with their credentials used at the website 
I managed to authenticate users via Xamarin.Auth to login via Google, Twitter... etc but could not figure out how to authenticate them via ASP.Net Identity provider.

any ideas or examples ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not a new one, and is one that will be easily fixed in the near future (see note below).

When you're authenticating with a provider like Google or Facebook, you're receiving a token that you can then use to send to the API. Unfortunately Asp.Net Identity does not do this out of the box. You can either configure your API to use JwtBearer tokens, or check out the [Identity4 project](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) along with their [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts). Note that if you're using Asp.Net Identity you'll probably want a cross between Quickstart 6 and Quickstart 8 so that all of the necessary persistent stores are in your database.

NOTE: You might also want to follow the [Templating Team's PR #700](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/pull/700) which is adding token based auth in the new templates which will soon allow you to rapidly create new Api's with Token Based Authentication for your mobile apps.